# How do I create a bracketed file for Aurora HDR software?

Tags: post-processing, hdr, file-format, bracketing, in-camera-processing

I have a Samsung J7 phone and the Aurora HDR software and tried to create an HDR image file with the phone. The phone has an HDR mode in the camera app. The software requires a bracketed file to do its magic but the phone creates a file that's not bracketed. The software will only show a single image frame when the file is loaded.

I can easily make 3 copies of the image file with different exposures. Can you tell me how to create a bracketed file with those images so I can import it into the Aurora HDR software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phone's HDR mode will be doing what you want Aurora to do: taking three separate exposures and blending them into one. That is why you only see a single file. You need to use an app like Camera FV-5 to give you manual control, which will allow you to create 3 differently exposed images quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

To create an HDR Image (in any HDR software) you'll need to upload several photos taken at different exposure values. These shots are called brackets.
Then the software will create a single (bracketed) HDR image.  Aurora HDR Pro can work properly only with the brackets with different exposures that have been modified with the camera, not with other software. So, in order to get the best results with Aurora HDR Pro you should bracket the exposures while you`re photographing.
Aurora HDR Pro also works with just one image, though for better results, it's recommended to upload several photos.